# How to add a green border if validation is completed when submitting the form

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, form-validation, custom-validation

Magento 2 has basic validation if the field is not valid.
[image]

How to add custom validation to the checkout page which will add a green border and an inscription that notifies the user of a **successful validation**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution, it is working amazing

1. create you module or insert following code in theme requirejs-config.js

> ```
> var config = {
>     config: {
>         mixins: {
>             'mage/validation': {
>                 'Expert_Checkout/js/mage/validation-mixin': true
>             }   
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

1. validation-mixin.js

> ```
> define([
>     'jquery' ], function ($) {
>     'use strict';
>     var widgetMixin = {
>         _create: function() {
>             $(this.element).find('input, textarea, select').on("change keyup", function(e){
>               $.validator.validateSingleElement(e.currentTarget)
>             });
>             return this._super();
>         }
>     };
>     return function (parentWidget) {
>         $.widget('mage.validation', parentWidget, widgetMixin);
>         return $.mage.validation;
>     }; })
> ```

Now it will work on all forms and valdate field as user type and add class valid on success

Thanks